# How to insert a backbone model into a sub collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Models:

```
class Device extends Backbone.Model
    url: '/device'
    initialize: ->
        console.log "Device model created..."
        @set
            controllers: new Controllers

class Controller extends Backbone.Model
```

Collection:

```
class Controllers extends Backbone.Collection
    model: Controller
```

Code:

```
device = new Device
controller = new Controller
controller1 = new Controller
controller.set
   name: "state1"
   value: "on"
controller1.set
   name: "state2"
   value: "on"
device.set 
   id: 1
   name: "foo"
   controllers: [controller, controller1]
```

Error message (when using .each on "controllers"):

> TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object] has no method 'each'

The idea is that each Device holds a sub collection of controllers. My simple question is how to add models to this sub collection? The code above seems to override the collection with an array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the attribute `controllers` with an `array`. Since its a collection, you need to use either `add` or `reset`, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: yeah. I realised that. But how do I use add on an attribute to a model?

Comment: In javascript terms: `device.get('controllers').add([{...}])`